# Is there any reason not to group class properties?

Tags: php, coding-style

I use docblocks to typehint class properties, and only recently realised that class properties may be grouped as such:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstname, $surname, $location;
```

Which is way easier to read, and shorter, than this:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $location;
```

Would there be any reason not to do this?

Comment: probably for comments that what variable is used for.

Comment: I really really hate 99,9% of variable comments. Type + name should be enough. If it isn't, you probably named it wrong.

Comment: Certain things are a matter of taste and personal preference. If you find your first example good for your use case then there is no reason *not* to use it. Some people will prefer the 2nd approach, some will prefer the 1st approach. This is totally up to you to decide what you want to use.

Comment: Why the close votes? Whether the style suits you or not is opinion based, but I'm just checking to see if I overlook something of a different nature.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer 1st approach, because PSR-2 [says](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#4-2-properties) "There MUST NOT be more than one property declared per statement.". There are good reasons for that, and here are some of my thoughts I guess authors of PSR-2 had too:

- people don't expect to see more than one declaration per line (at least me and my collegues);
- it's more difficult to change type of a variable, e.g. of `$location` from string to a Location class.
- it's more difficult to read diffs: the line will be marked as changed by VCS if name of any variable changes, and reviewer will have to read the whole line. Such line has higher probability of changing;
- it's not easy to comment a single variable from a group.